# XML feed to show on my facebook page

Tags: xml, facebook

I was hoping some one could point me to some good tutorial/examples on how I would take an XML feed from my website and show it on my facebook page or even answer if it cant be done. And also if I have to render the data before its sent to my facebook page or if the facebook api could do this?

Thanks

John

Answer (score 0):

It's not suppose to be a problem- God Bless SIMPLEXML. Just write some ordinary php code.

Comment: @WildBlade - Can you use php code on your facebook page? I want to show my websites data on my facebook page not my facebook data on my website.

Comment: @John-Yeah I got that:) A nice way of doing this is using FBML (though deprecated-http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/ ) - should still be a good way for you. What you want to do is use the tag used to print HTML (can't remember which one) and create an Jeramey hosted on your server. It's like an internal app inside your facebook page. The simple way to know this works, is the fact that you have lots of pages with flash contents on them-obviously grabbed via iframes due to the fact that facebook does not allow flash on anywhere except iframe apps and videos.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a page on your website that will display your feed in a nice way. Test it until it's OK. let say it's at url : http://www.yoursite.com/feedforfacebook/

2) Now go to http://facebook.com/developers and click on "setup new app".
Select an application name, click agree, fill the captcha.

3) Now you have to fill the urls correctly in the "Web Site" and "Facebook Integration" part.
If we keep the url from above it would be :

```
Web Site > Site URL : http://www.yoursite.com/
Web Site > Site Domain : yoursite.com

Facebook Integration > Canvas Page : SOME_SHORT_NAME (so it will be http://apps.facebook.com/SOME_SHORT_NAME)
Facebook Integration > Canvas URL : http://www.yoursite.com/feedforfacebook/
Facebook Integration > Iframe Size : Auto-resize
Facebook Integration > Tab Name : Choose a tab name for integrating in your Page.
Facebook Integration > Tab URL : http://www.yoursite.com/feedforfacebook/
Facebook Integration > Secure Tab URL : http**s**://www.yoursite.com/feedforfacebook/ (if available)
```

Then click Save.
(In this setup I suppose that you use the same URL for Tab Content and Canvas Content (http://www.yoursite.com/feedforfacebook/)

But you could use two different URLs for these 2 like http://www.yoursite.com/feedforfacebook/canvas/ and http://www.yoursite.com/feedforfacebook/tab/ if you want 2 different versions.

So to explain a little bit the Canvas URL will be used if you visit your application in "full application mode", that is if you visit http://apps.facebook.com/SOME_SHORT_NAME, you will see a facebook page, with a big iframe of 760px wide that will point to your specified "Canvas URL" and that will be your facebook application in "full canvas mode"

Now if you want the tab mode, it will still display the same content in an iframe, but inside a page tab. Here the iframe would be 520 px wide and would point to "Tab URL"

Now when you are done with this you can add the newly created tab to your page, to do this go to : http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php

On the left side their should be your newly created app, click on it, the content in the middle will change to display information about your newly created app. click on "Application Profile Page", you will be redirected to the "profile page" of your application.

Then on this profile page, if everything is setup correctly, in the down left part of you page you will find "Add to my Page". Click on it, then select your page. Then you are done : You will have a new tab added to your page that will be named after your settings... and that will display your feed page inside a nice iframe.

Feel free to ask any question if it's not clear.

Comment: I wouldnt recommend using FBML as WideBlade proposed, first because FBML just sucks and secondly because facebook noticed it and is on its way to deprecate FBML completely so in the long term it is not a good solution. The "iframe" way is the way to go now for apps on facebook (and it's a lot easier than FBML anyway)